# Background Tasks Infrastructure Service event id 7046

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-event-log, windows-service

I have a server running W2K12 R2.  The server experiences a string of Event ID 7011 entries in the System Event log followed by Event ID 7046.

7011 error text states "A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the BrokerInfrastructure service." (3 times)
followed by three of them for the DCOMLaunch Service, followed by one for SystemsEventsBroker Service, then two for the LSM service.

Then 7046 hits with "The following service has repeatedly stopped responding to service control requests: Background Tasks Infrastructure Service" and then file share access is lost until the server is rebooted.  I have had two occurrences spaced 8 days apart.

Comments are welcome.